# Can't check if user logged into Facebook by Activity Feed plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I've got problem with Activity Feed and event in JavaScript-SDK. When user log in in activity plugin I would like to detect that and redirect him somwhere else. Everything works fine when user log by fb:login button.

Is there possible way to detect that user logged in by this activity feed box?

Comment: Does the activity feed plugin actually log the user into your app, or just to Facebook? if the latter, there's no reason there'd be a specific callback

Comment: @Igy Didn't really think of that. It must be the only reason why fb.getLoginStatus() doesn't react. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Activity Feed is a Social Plugin, meaning: It is pretty closed and you can only do specific things with it. It does not authorize the user to your app. That´s why there is the Login Button, which is also a Social Plugin for this specific task.

More info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/